# Set the ComboBox value in a Table Cell C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, cell

The project that I am doing is kind of like a bot, I grab my application's process (its for some automated q&a testing) and then add values and edit values in the app and see if the output is as expected.

Well, I have gotten the application window (called window) and I'm looking to get a DataGridView item which has been added into the other application. I know it's called "dataGridView1", and the UI interface that I'm using (SpecFlow and White.Core) do not support grabbing the DataGridView item from another application

As a workaround, I grab the DataGridView item as a table.
Now, the problem. I am trying to set a cell value in the data grid view in which that cell
contains a ComboBox, which Table does not support selecting. Everytime I perform a Cell.SetValue(string) it will set the value *temporarily* until I navigate away on my UI

So basically, my question is, is there any way that I can set the value of a table cell that is supposed to be a DataGridView cell that contains a combobox? I have added a few comments in the code for what I would like to happen

```
public void InsertValues(String price, String name)
    {

     //actually is the following
     //DataGridView Data = window.Get<DataGridView>("dataGridView1");
     //but this is not supported by the White.Core.UIItems.

        Table Data = window.Get<Table>("dataGridView1");
        int numRows = 0;
        foreach (White.Core.UIItems.TableItems.TableRow tbr in Data.Rows)
            numRows++;

 //get the last row in the table
        White.Core.UIItems.TableItems.TableRow leaseRow = Data.Rows[numRows - 1];


        White.Core.UIItems.TableItems.TableCell PriceCell = leaseRow.Cells["price_val"];
        White.Core.UIItems.TableItems.TableCell NameCell = leaseRow.Cells["name_val"];


//set the values of the various cells in the table 
        PriceCell.Click();
        PriceCell.SetValue(pricingFormulaName);
        PriceCell.Enter(pricingFormulaName);

        NameCell.Click();
        NameCell.SetValue(feeScheduleName);
        NameCell.Enter(feeScheduleName);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Q&A automation, I would Highly recommend Selenium...You can make either a html script or in your case a C# application to run threw it and with selenium you can specify

```
      driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Body']/form/div/div[2]/div[13]/div/div/div/div[2]/button")).Click();
```

Or

```
     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'[add]')]")).Click();
```

if its in the css or you can call it by ID...And best part is Selenium is open Source...Or Maybe in SpecFlow  you can specify a CSS Selection or XPath like how I did in Selenium